# Write the output of the VariantAnnotation package to file

Tags: r, bioconductor, variation

I'm having some problems in exporting the annotations of some variants from a VCF file, after using the "[VariantAnnotation](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/VariantAnnotation.html)" package from bioconductor. Below the script I've used:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

library(VariantAnnotation)
library(BSgenome.Scerevisiae.UCSC.sacCer3)
library(TxDb.Scerevisiae.UCSC.sacCer3.sgdGene)

args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)

vcf <- readVcf(args[1], "sacCer3")

sc <- BSgenome.Scerevisiae.UCSC.sacCer3
txdb <- TxDb.Scerevisiae.UCSC.sacCer3.sgdGene

coding <- data.frame(predictCoding(vcf, txdb, seqSource=sc))
```

The `coding` dataframe looks like this:

```
  seqnames start end width strand paramRangeID REF     ALT QUAL FILTER
1     chrI   455 455     1      +         <NA>   C       T   40   PASS
2     chrI   455 455     1      +         <NA>   C           40   PASS
3     chrI   455 455     1      +         <NA>   C       G   40   PASS
4     chrI   455 455     1      +         <NA>   C       A   40   PASS
5     chrI   456 456     1      +         <NA>   T       A   40   PASS
6     chrI   456 456     1      +         <NA>   C CCTGCTC   40   PASS
  varAllele CDSLOC.start CDSLOC.end CDSLOC.width PROTEINLOC QUERYID TXID CDSID
1         T          121        121            1         41       1    1     1
2                    121        121            1         41       2    1     1
3         G          121        121            1         41       3    1     1
4         A          121        121            1         41       4    1     1
5         A          122        122            1         41       5    1     1
6   CCTGCTC          122        122            1         41       6    1     1
   GENEID    CONSEQUENCE REFCODON  VARCODON REFAA VARAA
1 YAL069W  nonsynonymous      CTC       TTC     L     F
2 YAL069W not translated      CTC        TC            
3 YAL069W  nonsynonymous      CTC       GTC     L     V
4 YAL069W  nonsynonymous      CTC       ATC     L     I
5 YAL069W  nonsynonymous      CTC       CAC     L     H
6 YAL069W  nonsynonymous      CTC CCCTGCTCC     L   PCS
```

But if I try to save it to file, for instance using the following command:

```
write.table(coding, 'test.tsv', sep='\t', row.names=F)
```

The output table looks like this:

```
"seqnames"      "start" "end"   "width" "strand"        "paramRangeID"  "REF"   "ALT"   "QUAL"  "FILTER"        "varAllele"     "CDSLOC.start"  "CDSLOC.end"    "CDSLOC.width"  "PROTEINLOC"    "QUERYID"       "TXID"  "CDSID" "GENEID"        "CONSEQUENCE"   "REFCODON"      "VARCODON"      "REFAA" "VARAA"             
"chrI"  455     455     1       "+"     NA      "C"     <S4 object of class "DNAStringSet">     40      "PASS"  "T"     121     121     1       41      1       "1"     1       "YAL069W"       "nonsynonymous" "CTC"   "TTC"   "L"     "F"                            
"chrI"  455     455     1       "+"     NA      "C"     <S4 object of class "DNAStringSet">     40      "PASS"  ""      121     121     1       41      2       "1"     1       "YAL069W"       "not translated" "CTC"   "TC"    ""      ""
```

Notice the `<S4 object of class "DNAStringSet">` bit. Is there any way to force R to give me the same representation as `head`? I couldn't find anything in Biostrings' documentation.

Comment: You might be able to convert the DNAStringSet to character and then store it. But it might be a function available to store a GRange to a file I am not aware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to force R to give me the same representation as `head`?

`head` just cuts off everything after the first six entries. The magic, as it were, happens in the default `print` method for the specific type. But the representation generated by it is only useful for ad-hoc display, not for storage in a structured data file.

The best solution is therefore to manually convert the column types. Since it’s only one column:

```
coding$ALT = sapply(coding$ALT, as.character)
```

I’m a bit puzzled that the `REF` and `ALT` column have different types, anyway: that’s probably a bug in the {VariantAnnotation} package that should be reported.

Furthermore, you probably want to use `quote = FALSE` for the `write.table`. In general, `write.table` has terrible defaults. `readr::write_tsv` is almost always a better choice.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I perform `as.character(coding$ALT)` (not REF, that gets written fine) I get a `"<S4 object of class \"DNAStringSet\">"`

Comment: I removed the cast to `data.frame` around the `predictCoding` function and now I get this message when trying to cast to character: `Error in as.vector(x, mode = "character") : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector`

Comment: @mgalardini That’s bizarre, it works for me. But maybe try loading the {Biostrings} package explicitly — it sounds like the method call is incorrectly dispatched (but it works for me even without attaching the package; as it should).

Comment: If this continues to not work you can also try to invoke `as.character` on individual `DNAString`s, like so: `sapply(coding$REF, as.character)`. However, if the former doesn’t work I fear the latter won’t either.

Comment: This last suggestion actually worked; I ignore while the others didn't... I'll update your answer, and thanks a lot!